# URLs Amigáveis Nginx

Tags: htaccess, nginx

Estou tentando criar uma URLamigável em meu servidor,
anteriormente eu utilizava o apache com este `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?subtopic=$1
```

Após mudar para o nginx passei a utilizar:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?subtopic=$1;
```

Porém ele não está redirecionando como deveria, quando tento acessar qualquer pagina ele joga para a pagina 404

Comment: Se possível posta o código do seu bloco. O `DocumentRoot` está correto? Já tentou com `try_files` ?

Comment: tentei via try_files também, não obtive o resultado esperado, como seria o correto ?

Comment: O `DocumentRoot` está correto?  Se possível posta o código que você testou usando `try_files`